# How to define XAML DesignData in WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I am working on Windows 8.1 app.

I have a `Page`:

```
<Page d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/MySampleData.xaml}" 
      x:Class="xxx.MyView"
      ...>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyString}"/>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime}"/>
</Page>
```

Then I have `MySampleData.xaml`:

```
<local:MyViewModel
 ...
 xmlns:local="using:xxx.ViewModels" 
 MyString="my text"
 StartTime="2014/01/01"/>
```

In `MyViewModel.cs` I have:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string MyString {get; set;}
    public DateTime StartTime {get; set;}
}
```

In designer it displays correctly, but when compiling I get this error in my `MySampleData.xaml`:

> Cannot assign text value '2014/01/01' into property 'StartTime' of type 'DateTime'

The part for `MyString` works perfectly, but the `StartTime` does not (it did in Windows 8.0), any idea how to get it working? And why does it try to compile the design data?

#### Additional Resources

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041730/datetime-xaml-winrt), the reason is because WinRT does not support `TypeConverters`.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965853/how-to-have-designtime-data-in-winrt-xaml), it proposes that you create a fake class, but I really want to do it in XAML.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I created this class:

```
public class Jerry
{
    public DateTime SampleDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

And, using Blend, it created this sample data:

```
<App47:Jerry xmlns:App47="using:App47" 
    xmlns:System="using:System" 
    SampleDateTime="12/11/2014 17:00:25" />
```

Based on that, I think you just need to include the time string.

Best of luck!

Comment: This is still a very weird issue (I do include System), it displays the data correctly in designer; but then cannot compile, it gives an error: **Cannot assign text value '12/11/2014 17:00:25' into property 'StartTime' of type 'DateTime'**. Which is very strange, why does it try to compile the design data?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in the question. I've updated it.

Comment: Have you tried starting from scratch with a simpler class? Just to prove this is a problem in XAML and not a problem with your class?

Comment: Jip :P a few times. Even tried from a blank project.

Comment: Sorry about this. Since it works for me in a blank project, and doesn't work for you in a blank project, I am not sure where to go from here. Have you tried lighting a candle? (j/k)

Comment: :D hehehe, thank you for all your effort, really appreciate it! I have actually given up on this, and will once again make time if I can find time to spend on it.